# jest and localStorage

Tags: local-storage, jestjs

I'm trying to test localStorage with jest:

```
    it("changes the localStorage", () => {
      const changeLocale = (languageLocale) => {
        localStorage.setItem("language", languageLocale);
        return {
          type: "CHANGE_LOCALE",
          locale: languageLocale
        };
      }


      const locale = "de";

      localStorage.clear();

      changeLocale(locale);

      expect(localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(LOCAL_LANG, locale);
      expect(localStorage.__STORE__[LOCAL_LANG]).toBe(locale);
    });
```

When I'm trying to run it with `npm run test`, it returns an error like this:

```
expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenLastCalledWith()

jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
Received:
  function: [Function setItem]

  33 |       changeLocale(locale);
  34 |
> 35 |       expect(localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(LOCAL_LANG, locale);
     |                                    ^
  36 |       expect(localStorage.__STORE__[LOCAL_LANG]).toBe(locale);
  37 |     });
  38 |   });
```

I use jest-localstorage-mock. Could you please pinpoint why could I get that error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to get rid of `jest-localstorage-mock` usage.
Instead, I do `spyOn` like this:

```
jest.spyOn(Storage.prototype, 'setItem');
jest.spyOn(Storage.prototype, 'getItem');
```

So the entire solution looks like this:

```
it('changes the localStorage', () => {
  const changeLocale = languageLocale => {
    localStorage.setItem('language', languageLocale);
    return {
      type: 'CHANGE_LOCALE',
      locale: languageLocale
    };
  }

  const locale = 'de';

  jest.spyOn(Storage.prototype, 'setItem');
  jest.spyOn(Storage.prototype, 'getItem');

  localStorage.clear();

  changeLocale(locale);

  expect(localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(LOCAL_LANG, locale);
  expect(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_LANG)).toBe(locale);
});
```

Hope it is helpful to someone :)